# How may I call a specific function that is conditional on sampling frequencies in Matlab?

Tags: function, conditional-statements, frequency, sampling

In Matlab, I wish to call a function indexed by a designated label (i.e 1,2,3 or 4) across X number of trials with the frequency of (3,1,1,1) respectively (i.e the function designated by 1 is 3 times more likely to be called than functions designated by 2,3 and 4). I was thinking of initialising a vector of length X according to the following code:

```
R = randsample([1 2 3 4], 1000, true, [3 1 1 1])
```

Before calling a for loop to the effect (please forgive the pseudo-code):

```
for i=1:length(R)
if R(i) = 1;
   'insert function 1'
if R(i) = 2;
   'insert function 2'
if R(i) = 3;
   'insert function 3'
if R(i) = 4;
   'insert function 4'
```

May anyone assist?  Many thanks.